# Auto refresh an HTML div every X secounds

Tags: php, jquery, html

**index.html**

```
<frameset rows="150%,35%" framespacing="1" frameborder="yes" border="1">
<div class="refresh"><frame src="messages.php" name="main_frame"></div>
<frame src="main.php" name="login_frame" scrolling="no" noresize target="middle">
```

I want the refresh div to reload every X secounds.

**messange.php**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
<?php
require_once('inc/chat.inc.php');
$oSimpleChat = new SimpleChat();
echo $oSimpleChat->getMessages();
?>
```

*Chat.inc.php have the MySQL Query to get the messanges.*

I don't want the whole page to reload, so I removed the content refresh

**I found this script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        j(".refresh").everyTime(1000,function(i){
            j.ajax({
              url: "messanges.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j(".refresh").html(html);
              }
            })
        })
    });
});
```

But when I put that script in my index.html file it will not auto refreash.

Answer (score 0):

The url is incorrect

You are using "messange.php" and it should be "messages.php"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        j(".refresh").everyTime(1000,function(i){
            j.ajax({
              url: "messages.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j(".refresh").html(html);
              }
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the messanges appeared, but it still wount auto refreash.. but i'm gonna edit my post question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (not tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            j.ajax({
              url: "messanges.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j(".refresh").html(html);
              }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```